# Flashlight app not turning off in kitkat device. perfectly working on marshmallow

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is my code of my flashlight app which is perfectly run on my nougat and marshmallow device. but when i test it to a kitkat device, flashlight turn on perfectly, but not turning off. 
Whats wrong i did in this code can you help me to find it please..
I didnt find any solution in the web. please help.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button btnSwitch;
    private Camera camera;
    private boolean isFlashOn;
    private boolean hasFlash;
    Camera.Parameters params;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Camera.Parameters parameters;
    private CameraManager camManager;
    private Context context;


    ImageView imageFlashlight;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 50;
    private boolean flashLightStatus = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageFlashlight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageFlashlight);



        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        // First check if device is supporting flashlight or not
        hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);


        final boolean hasCameraFlash = getPackageManager().
                hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
        boolean isEnabled = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        // get the camera


        // displaying button image


        imageFlashlight.setEnabled(isEnabled);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_REQUEST);



        imageFlashlight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (hasCameraFlash) {

                    if (flashLightStatus) {
                        turnOffFlash();
                    } else

                        turnOnFlash();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No flash available on your device",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }


        });


    }



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void turnOnFlash() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

            try {
                String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
                flashLightStatus = true;
                imageFlashlight.setImageResource(R.drawable.poweron);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            }
        } else {


            imageFlashlight.setImageResource(R.drawable.poweron);

            getCamera();
            params = camera.getParameters();
            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
            isFlashOn = true;

        }
    }

    // Get the camera
    private void getCamera() {
        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Camera Error. ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void turnOffFlash() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

            try {
                String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
                flashLightStatus = false;
                imageFlashlight.setImageResource(R.drawable.poweroff);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            }
        } else {
getCamera();
            if (flashLightStatus) {
                if (isFlashOn = true) {
                    return;
                }

                params = camera.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.stopPreview();
                isFlashOn = false;
            }
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_REQUEST:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    imageFlashlight.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied for the Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `flashLightStatus` because you are not setting it inside `else` part of `turnOnFlash` method and later inside `turnOffFlash`,

```
if (flashLightStatus) {
```

will never be true hence control will never reach the point to turn off light so do

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try {
            String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
            imageFlashlight.setImageResource(R.drawable.poweron);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        }
    } else {


        imageFlashlight.setImageResource(R.drawable.poweron);

        getCamera();
        params = camera.getParameters();
        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();

    }
       isFlashOn = true;
       flashLightStatus = true;
}
```

and also use

```
if (!isFlashOn) {
     return;
}
```

instead of

```
if (isFlashOn = true) {
    return;
}
```

to return control when flash light is not on

Comment: O god! Thank you so much sir, you just save me. thanks a lot.  One more question please, I added a button on this main activity called red theme (It was blue). when user click the button they will go to another activity, there will be same thing like main activity. just on click color will be change.  i've already done it, activity get change but when i click to flash on button it crashed. do i need to change any method for second activity to turn on flash??

Comment: @Adam just follow the crash `error` details in logcat view (on left bottom) to see the cause and resolve it and to turn on flash in second activity, you need the same setup and probably wants to shut down flash control of previous activity in on pause, rest depends upon the implementation, you can use service etc